# Quadrado não aparece no meu código CSS

Tags: html, css

Estou dando meus primeiros passos em html e esbarrei em meu primeiro quebra cabeça.
Nesse pequeno "portifólio" que estou fazendo tentei acrescentar a imagem de um quadrado , já tinha feito alguns testes e funcionou muito bem ,mas ao tentar acrescentar a figura no código deste exercício em específico a figura não aparece ....ja tentei colocá-lo em outras posições no código e até agora não funcionou,agradeço muito se alguém poder me dar uma força o código segue abaixo:

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

.square {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Nicolas Amad</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!--Cabeçalho da página-->
  <div>
    <center>
      <img width="300px" height="300" src="Perfil.jpeg">
      <hr/>
      <h1 style="color:white;"><big>Nicolas Amad</big></h1>
</body>
<hr/>
<div class="square"></div>
</center>
</div>

<!--Auto-Descrição-->

<h2 style="color:white;"><u>Quem sou eu?</u></h2>

<p style="color:white;"> Estudante de Engenharia Mecânica e Análise de Sistemas ,apaixonado pelo poder de criação que a tecnologia oferece, atualmente muito interesado em Desenvolvimento Web/Mobile.</p>

<br><br>

<!--Descrição de Habilidades--->
<h3 style="color:white;"><u><b>Skills</b></u></h3>

<table>
  <tr>

    <td style="color:white;"><b>HTML</b></td>
    <td>
      <div class="square"></div>
    </td>

  </tr>

</table>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Seu *HTML* possui dois elementos [`<body>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body). O elemento `<body>` representa o conteúdo de um documento *HTML*. è permitido apenas um `<body>` por documento.

Comment: Muito obrigado Augusto,resolveu meu problema perfeitamente ,ainda me confundo muito em alguns detalhes.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, boa noite!
Existem alguns erros no seu código que deve se atentar.

**1 -** O `<body></body>` é o corpo da página, e entre ele deve ficar todo conteúdo ao qual você quer que apareça visualmente na sua página e não pode ser repetido.

1. `<html>`
2. `<head></head>`
3. `<body></body>`
4. `</html>`

**2 -** Parece que o seu código em CSS está em um arquivo externo. Se estiver, você precisa inserir o link do arquivo dentro da tag `<head></head>`.
Assim: `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="MeuArquivo.css">`

Eu editei o seu arquivo, fiz algumas correções. Estude o código e veja no que você errou. São coisas simples. Bons estudos.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Nicolas Amad</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: green;
        }

        .square{
            height: 20px;
            width: 20px;
            background-color: #555; 
        }
    </style>
    </head>

<body>
    <!--Cabeçalho da página-->
    <div>
            <center>
              <img width="300px" height="300" src="Perfil.jpeg">
                <hr/>
                    <h1 style="color:white;"><big>Nicolas Amad</big></h1>
                <hr/>
            </center>
          <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    
<!--Auto-Descrição-->
<h2 style="color:white;"><u>Quem sou eu?</u></h2>
<p style="color:white;"> Estudante de Engenharia Mecânica e Análise de Sistemas ,apaixonado pelo poder de criação que a tecnologia oferece, atualmente muito interesado em Desenvolvimento Web/Mobile.</p>

<br><br>

<!--Descrição de Habilidades--->
<h3 style="color:white;"><u><b>Skills</b></u></h3>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style="color:white;"><b>HTML</b></td>
        <td>
          <div class="square"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```